# MySQL create index sum of two columns data in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

```
 >> table1
 -------------------------------------------------------------
 | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 |
 +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
 |  data1  |  data2  |  data3  |  data4  |  data5  |  data6  |
 +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
 |  data7  |  data8  |  data9  |  data10 |  data11 |  data12 | 
 +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
                               .
                               .
                               .
 +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
 |  data   |  data   |  data   |  data   |  data   |  data   | 
 -------------------------------------------------------------

 >> query
 SELECT * FROM table1
     WHERE (column5 + column6) >= 6;
```

How do I create an index for this query in MySQL?

Comment: An index might not help this particular query because you are adding together the two columns.

Comment: in Postgresql it would be `CREATE INDEX sumthing ON  table1 (( column5 + column6 ));` for mysql i don't know.

Comment: Oh, I forgot, the data types of columns 5 and 6 are int.

Comment: @Jasen thx, but your query is not work in mysql.

Comment: I don’t understand the relevance of the other columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can create an index on the sum of two columns.

You could add an additional field that contains column5 + column6 and index on that.

You could create a view with an additional column equal to column5 + column6 and index on that.

Comment: Hi John, I agree with creating a computed column, but I'm not sure if it is possible to index a view in MySQL.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, no indexes on views, sorry for the bad advice.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the advice. I think I should study harder.

Comment: @JohnBiddle I don't know why I can comment on only one person at once.
Thank you for your kind answers.

Answer (score 2):

*Newer* versions of MySQL (5.7.6) (and MariaDB in 5.2 with `VIRTUAL` columns) have "Generated" columns.  You would create such as (col5+col6), then index this fake column.  Such a column can be `STORED` in the table our could be `VIRTUAL`.  Read the docs to get the details.

```
col56 GENERATED ALWAYS AS (col5 + col6) VIRTUAL  -- or STORED
```

Comment: I do not want to create a new column. But thanks for telling me the new way.